# How can I make the image size smaller on a button?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a button and I want image (.ico file) and text to exist on it. My problem is that I want button's height to be small, but I can't manage to "shrink" the image as much as I want to. The result is to have a piece of image visible on the button and not the hole image. At the image property the image size is fixed (48x48) and the option is grey so I can't change it. How can I make this image to be 16x16?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Try `buttonname.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;` or change this property in designer.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I have already tried that, it doesn't work.

Comment: Looks like you set .ico as button.image instead of button.backgroundimage; plz let me know if thats the case.

Comment: Yes the background image can be centered, zoomed, tiled etc and you were right I used image and not background image. But the funny think is that I use the exact same properties and image size with a toolstrip's button. There thinks were OK, and here I can't manage to do what I want. When I use background image as you suggested, "zoom" seams to be a proper setting, but keeps the image at the center of the button and cannot go left or right

Comment: I just saw that an ordinary button does not have a "display style" property like a tooolstrip button.

Comment: You have to use background image instead of foreground image for that solution to work.

Answer (score 37):

My solution was to use an ImageList control.  You can define the size the images are to be displayed (e.g. I set the ImgageList ImageSize property to 16x16) and then set the button.ImageList and ImageIndex properties instead of the Image property.

Comment: i think its answer the question...Thnks

Comment: Thanks!. I think this is a better solution than the one suggested by @Zaphood

Answer (score 1):

I think if you use the **Paint event** of the Button you can draw any image in any size that you want. if it isn't possible to re-size the image you can do that in this way.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Image with size 16*16 then set these Button properties at design time.
   1) TextImageRelation - ImageBeforeText
   2) TextAlign - MiddleRight
   3) ImageAlign - MiddleLeft
   4) Set the

Answer (score 0):

```
ImageList imageList = new ImageList();
imageList.ImageSize = new Size(30, 30); // specify size you want
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: To add to @fcdt 's comment, please have a look here too: [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score -1):

If you are using DevExpress Simple Button, you should set BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Zoom and set backcolor of button to **Transparent** (from **Appereance->Backcolor**)