# Making a background image scale with button size

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I'm trying to add some background images to a few buttons in my Win Forms application.  The three images are different sizes (ie pixel dimensions don't match, one is 128x128 and another is 256x256).  I need the buttons to be identical in size (otherwise the GUI is horribly asymmetrical).  Without changing the actual image files, how can I get the images to scale with button size?

I've tried creating my own class, and adding an event handler for the button resize event, but that doesn't seem to work.  My code:

```
class CustomButton : Button {

        internal void CustomButton_Resize( object sender, EventArgs e ) {
            if ( this.BackgroundImage == null ) {
                return;
            }

            var pic = new Bitmap( this.BackgroundImage, this.Width, this.Height );
            this.BackgroundImage = pic;
        }
    }
```

and in the form:

```
this.buttonOne.Resize += new System.EventHandler(this.buttonOne.CustomButton_Resize);
```

Forgot to mention, the above code does not resize the images at all.  The buttons still need to have different sizes to display the images completely.

Comment: I had tried to write the same thing in concise way but could not succeed. At least please improve the look of code :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**The easy programmatic way**

Say I have a button `btn1`, Following code is working perfectly in visual-studio-2010.

```
private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btn1.Width = 120;
    btn1.Height = 100;
}
void btn1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ( this.BackgroundImage == null )
          return;
    var bm = new Bitmap(btn1.BackgroundImage, new Size(btn1.Width, btn1.Height));
    btn1.BackgroundImage = bm;
}
```

**The better way**

You can add eventHandler in the constructor of your custombutton (just to ensure that you are adding eventhandler correctly)

```
class CustomButton : Button
{    
    CustomButton()
    {
        this.Resize += new System.EventHandler(buttonOne.CustomButton_Resize);
    }
    void CustomButton_Resize( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
       if ( this.BackgroundImage == null )
          return;
       var pic = new Bitmap( this.BackgroundImage, new Size(this.Width, this.Height) );
       this.BackgroundImage = pic;          
    }
}
```

Now when you will resize the button anywhere your image will get fit(scaled) to its new size.

Comment: You would think something like this should already be part of the .NET Button class!

Answer (score 14):

**Easiest way to add a background image to a .NET Button object and scale it to fit**

I used this method to avoid any additional coding of new classes and event handlers.  This helped me also avoid converting all Button objects into Image objects.

1. Add image to your Resources.resx file.
2. Click on your chosen button.
3. Navigate to the `BackgroundImage` property and choose the image you imported into the project's resources.resx file.
4. Navigate to the `BackgroundImageLayout` property and choose `Stretch`.

Make sure you don't have anything entered for the `Image` and `Text` properties or else they will interfere with your new background image.

Comment: This probably has the drawback that the image is not grayed out when the button is disabled. In that case an [ImageList](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23586776/993388) could help.

Answer (score 1):

You could start with something like this...

```
 public class ImageButton : Control
{
    public Image backgroundImage;

    public Image BackgroundImage
    {
        get
        {
            return backgroundImage;
        }
        set
        {
            backgroundImage = value;
            Refresh();
        }
    }

    public ImageButton()
    {

    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.Clear(BackColor);

        if(BackgroundImage != null)
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(BackgroundImage, 0, 0, Width, Height);

        base.OnPaint(e);
    }

    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs pevent)
    {
        //base.OnPaintBackground(pevent);
    }
}
```

You can just handle paint and draw the image yourself. You may also try using a PictureBox or some other control which has more scaling options