# Resize image included in button when resize

Tags: c#, winforms, button

I have a button with an included image and a text :

[image: Button with image OK]

When I resize my application, I resize the label to fit with the new button's height but the image is not resized :

[image: BUtton with image KO]

I saw a solution is to set image to `BackgroundImage` but it does not match the design of my button :

```
this.buttonClose.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
this.buttonClose.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("buttonClose.Image")));
this.buttonClose.Name = "buttonClose";
this.buttonClose.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(482, 28);
this.buttonClose.Text = "Close";
this.buttonClose.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
this.buttonClose.TextImageRelation = TextImageRelation.ImageBeforeText;
this.buttonClose.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
this.buttonClose.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.buttonClose_Click);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making a background image scale with button size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13357032/making-a-background-image-scale-with-button-size)

Comment: @fuchs777 as I said, I don't want to use `BackgroundImage` to have both Text and Image

Comment: _I don't want to use BackgroundImage to have both Text and Image_ But you __can have both__ with BackgrondImage as well! Plus tthe BackgroundImageLayout options of Stretch and Zoom!

Comment: @TaW Yes I can use `BackgroundImageLayout`, but I can't (or don't know how) define where image is displayed. In my close button, image and text are define as `ImageBeforeText` and both are center. I don't thing that I can have the same behavior with background. I was to consider text and Image like a block.

Comment: Ah, that's right. You can either add some empty space to the right of the image(s), create 2-3 versions of each or resize the image8s) on the fly.

Comment: @A.Pissicat you know that you could adapt that code to your needs? Maybe just replace BackgroundImage with Image in that example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution, maybe not the best but working fine :

```
private Dictionary<Button, Image> dicButtonsBaseImage = new Dictionary<Button, Image>();
private void SetImageButton(Button btn, Image img)
{
    // Initiate image for button
    btn.Image = img;

    // set method dor sizeChanged
    btn.SizeChanged += Control_SizeChanged;

    // Save image associated for this button
    if (!dicButtonsBaseImage.ContainsKey(btn))
        dicButtonsBaseImage.Add(btn, img);
    else
        dicButtonsBaseImage[btn] = img;

    // Init image size
    resizeImageSize(btn);
}

private void Control_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Control c = sender as Control;
    if (c != null)
    {
        Button b = sender as Button;
        if (b != null)
        {
            resizeImageSize(b);
        }
    }
}

private static void resizeImageSize(Button b)
{
    if (b.Image != null && dicButtonsBaseImage.ContainsKey(b))
    {
        // Set a margin (top/bot) to 8px
        if (b.Height - 8 < dicButtonsBaseImage[b].Height)
        {
            int newHeight = b.Height - 8;
            if (newHeight <= 0)
                newHeight = 1;
            Image img = new Bitmap(dicButtonsBaseImage[b], new Size(dicButtonsBaseImage[b].Width, newHeight));
            b.Image = img;
        }
        else
        {
            b.Image = dicButtonsBaseImage[b];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to automatically resize the application use this method

create class called resize

and paste this code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace YOUR APPLICATION NAMESPACE
{

   public class ClassResize
    {
       List<System.Drawing.Rectangle> AryControlsStorage = new List<System.Drawing.Rectangle>();
       private bool ShowRowHeader=false;

       private Form form { get; set; }
       private float FontSize { get; set; }
       private System.Drawing.SizeF FormSize { get; set; }

       public ClassResize(Form FForm)
       {
           form = FForm;
           FormSize = FForm.ClientSize;
           FontSize = FForm.Font.Size;
       }
       private static IEnumerable<Control> GetAllControls(Control c)
       {
           return c.Controls.Cast<Control>().SelectMany(item=>           
           GetAllControls(item)).Concat(c.Controls.Cast<Control>()).Where(control=>
                control.Name !=string.Empty);
       }
       public void GetInitialSize()
       {
           var _Controls = GetAllControls(form);
           foreach (Control control in _Controls)
           {
               AryControlsStorage.Add(control.Bounds);
               if (control.GetType() == typeof(DataGridView))
                   DGColumnAdjust(((DataGridView)control), ShowRowHeader);

           }

       }
       public void Resize()
       {
           double FormRatioWidth = (double)form.ClientSize.Width / (double)FormSize.Width;
           double FormRatioHeight=(double)form.ClientSize.Height / (double)FormSize.Height;
           var _Controls = GetAllControls(form);
           int Postion = -1;
           foreach(Control control in _Controls)
           {
               Postion += 1;
               System.Drawing.Size _ControlsSize = new System.Drawing.Size((int)(AryControlsStorage[Postion].Width * FormRatioWidth),
                   (int)(AryControlsStorage[Postion].Height * FormRatioHeight));
               System.Drawing.Point _ControlsPoint = new System.Drawing.Point((int)(AryControlsStorage[Postion].X * FormRatioWidth),
    (int)(AryControlsStorage[Postion].Y * FormRatioHeight));
               control.Bounds = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(_ControlsPoint, _ControlsSize);
               if (control.GetType() == typeof(DataGridView))
                   DGColumnAdjust(((DataGridView)control),ShowRowHeader);
               //control.Font = new System.Drawing.Font(form.Font.FontFamily,
               //(float)(((Convert.ToDouble(FontSize) * FormRatioWidth) / 1.5) + ((Convert.ToDouble(FontSize) * FormRatioHeight) / 1.5)));



           }

       }

       private void DGColumnAdjust(DataGridView dgv, bool _showRowHeader)
       {
           int intRowHeader = 0;
           const int Hscrolbarwidth = 5;
           if (_showRowHeader)
           {
               intRowHeader = dgv.RowHeadersWidth;
           }
           else
           {
               dgv.RowHeadersVisible = false;
           }
               for (int i = 0; i < dgv.ColumnCount; i++)
               {
                   if (dgv.Dock == DockStyle.Fill)
                       dgv.Columns[i].Width = ((dgv.Width - intRowHeader) / dgv.ColumnCount);
                   else
                       dgv.Columns[i].Width = ((dgv.Width - intRowHeader - Hscrolbarwidth) / dgv.ColumnCount);

               }
           }


    }
}
```

and call this class in you form

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Common;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


namespace YOUR NAMESPACE
{
    public partial class FORMNAME: Form
    {
             ClassResize Form;



        public FORMNAME()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
           Form = new ClassResize(this);


        }

    }
}
```

this will automatically resize your all controls in forms

Comment: yeah i know but this method over come resize problem

Comment: Well, he hasn't one. Only the Image has and I don't see how you code would help..